# Google maps API v3 JS: Why am I getting no return from this function?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API Geocoder to try and get lat/lng from an address.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function geocodeAddress(address) {
        geocoder.geocode({address:address}, function (results,status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var p = results[0].geometry.location;
                var lat=p.lat();
                var lng=p.lng();
                var location = '{'+lat+','+lng+'}';
                // If I alert(location) here, I get the correct lat/lng
                return location;
                // The return isn't happening?
            } else {
                alert('GeoCoder problem');
            }
        });
    }

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var point = geocodeAddress('Cape Town Carnival, Somerset Road, Green Point, South Africa');
    alert(point);  // this returns "Undefined".
</script>
```

This is in FF.  I am getting no JS errors. I am not a JS expert.  can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

J

Comment: It's an asynchronous call.  You need to call a function instead, and pass location as a parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `undefined` because `geocode()` is an async function. 
To get the result, you have to - for example - pass a callback function to your `geocodeAddress()` and call that when you have the location.

```
 function geocodeAddress(address, succCallback) {
        geocoder.geocode({address:address}, function (results,status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var p = results[0].geometry.location;
                var lat=p.lat();
                var lng=p.lng();
                var location = '{'+lat+','+lng+'}';

                succCallback(location);
            } else {
                alert('GeoCoder problem');
            }
        });
    }

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var point = geocodeAddress(
    'Cape Town Carnival, Somerset Road, Green Point, South Africa', 
    function(l) {
        alert(l);
    });
```